# ngChecked doesn't seem to want to bind to the model. Why?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and thus angularjs, and I'm trying to store a setting in localStorage.

I've a checkbox that I want to use to set analytics on or off. The html looks like this.

```
Analytics on/off
<label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAnalytics()" ng-checked="analytics">
        <div class="track">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
</label>
```

and in the related controller I have:

```
$scope.analytics = $localstorage.get('analyticsOnOff');
$log.log("Analytics initialised at", $scope.analytics);

$scope.toggleAnalytics = function(){ 

   if($scope.analytics===true){
      $scope.analytics = false;
      $localstorage.set('analyticsOnOff', false);
   }else{
      $scope.analytics = true;
      $localstorage.set('analyticsOnOff', true);
   } 

 $log.log("Analytics is ", $scope.analytics);

}
```

So as you can see, when you change the checkbox the toggleAnalytics() function toggles $scope.analytics between true and false and updates the localstorage to reflect that.

Note that I am using $localstorage methods. $localstorage is defined in another service. It's allows you to set and get localStorage objects easily.

Anyway, my issue is a really simple, but baffling one. I know I can alter the analytics value from the console logs, but no matter what I do the checkbox initialises as on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you using `ng-model` on that checkbox? It'll handle setting the `true` and `false`

Comment: `ng-checked` is for "When you have the expression as true, it will check". You are not setting anything on `analytics`.

Comment: @klauskpm No, check the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `$localstorage`, but perhaps `.get()` is returning a string value? That would cause the `ng-checked` expression to evaluate to true even for a `"false"` value.

Comment: @nickgraef, what did I said wrong? `If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "checked" will be set on the element` is in the docs.

Comment: @klauskpm sorry, I just saw your edit. You originally said `ng-checked` would perform an action when the checkbox was checked. All good now.

Comment: Yup. I edited right away when saw what I've writed :)

Comment: @nickgraef you are correct - .get() is returning a string! I've typeof'ed it. Now to convert it. How bizarre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for the feedback guys.

@nickgraef for altering me to the real problem - that .get() returns a string.

@tymeJV for supplying me with a much more elegant version of my own code.

This is what I did in the end, it's a mash up of both tips. I convert the analytics variable into a boolean straight after I .get() it from localstorage.

```
$scope.analytics = $localstorage.get('analyticsOnOff');
$scope.analytics = ($scope.analytics == 'true' ? true : false);

$log.log("Analytics initialised at", $scope.analytics);

$scope.toggleAnalytics = function(isChecked) { 
   $localstorage.set('analyticsOnOff', isChecked);
   $log.log("Analytics is ", isChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ng-model` on your checkbox, this will handle setting the actual property - and you can use a `change` event then:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggleAnalytics(analytics)" ng-model="analytics" />
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.toggleAnalytics = function(isChecked) { 
   $localstorage.set('analyticsOnOff', isChecked);
   $log.log("Analytics is ", isChecked);
}
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution but I've actually found out that the issue is related to the .get method - it returns a string! Now I need to find out why and how to convert it.

Comment: Only 225 for the week?  You're slipping!

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 -- Might need to take some PTO next week and get the stats back up!